# iOS UITableViewCell animation delay on load not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I've got some pretty simple code running in the `UITableViewDelegate` method `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` as seen here:

```
            [interestCell.imageView setAlpha:0.0];
            [interestCell.textLabel setAlpha:0.0];
            [interestCell setFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width, cell.frame.origin.y, cell.frame.size.width, cell.frame.size.height)];
            CGFloat delayForCellAnimation = ((indexPath.row+1)+(indexPath.section+1))*0.15f;//((indexPath.row+1)+(indexPath.section+1))*0.2f+0.5f;
            NSLog(@"delay: %f", delayForCellAnimation);
            [interestCell setFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width, cell.frame.origin.y, cell.frame.size.width, cell.frame.size.height)];
            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f delay:delayForCellAnimation options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowAnimatedContent animations:^{
                [interestCell.imageView setAlpha:0.6];
                [interestCell.textLabel setAlpha:0.6];
                [interestCell setFrame:CGRectMake(0, cell.frame.origin.y, cell.frame.size.width, cell.frame.size.height)];
            } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                [interestCell setHasAnimatedIn:YES];
                [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
                    [interestCell.imageView setAlpha:1.0];
                    [interestCell.textLabel setAlpha:1.0];
                }];
            }];
```

What I want to do is animate all the cells in from the right side of the table view. That is currently working, but I want the cells to animate on a delay so that the top cells can fly in before the bottom ones. I'm using the animation blocks above with a calculated delay, which I am logging to the console and it does calculate correctly (bigger values for later entries in the table), but the delays do not occur on the animations when I run the app. Any thoughts? Thank you.

Comment: Did a bunch of research on this, and still no clear cut answer. One theory was that frame is not an animatable property, but I've tried setting the "position" of the layers instead of the frames, and that doesn't work either. One strange thing is that I moved this code to viewDidAppear: and it doesn't work the first time viewDidAppear: gets called but it does on subsequent calls, so it must have to do with the lifecycle of the UITableView and its cells.

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to implement a `UITableView`-like controller with a `UICollectionView` and custom layout.  You could then use 
[`- initialLayoutAttributesForAppearingItemAtIndexPath:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewLayout_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UICollectionViewLayout/initialLayoutAttributesForAppearingItemAtIndexPath:) to position the cells off screen and let the collection view animate them to their real position (given by 
[`- layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewLayout_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UICollectionViewLayout/layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:)).

If a subclassed `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` doesn't implement enough table view features for you (e.g., sticky headers) you should take a look at [`CSStickyHeaderFlowLayout`](https://github.com/jamztang/CSStickyHeaderFlowLayout).